# Where do I put "use Rack::Facebook::MethodFix" to fix Facebook Post Canvas issue using Rack fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, post, canvas, rack

Looking at this solution https://github.com/tuupola/rack-facebook-method-fix it seems great except it omits what is probably obvious to most, but it's 5:30 in the morning and perhaps my brain is not working.  In what file and where should I put the lines:

```
require "rack-facebook-method-fix"
use Rack::Facebook::MethodFix
```

?  I assumed the top of application.rb but that gives me an error message:

```
/config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `use' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: I do not use Rails myself. However with Sinatra you just include those lines in main application.rb file.

Comment: thanks for the tip Mika - I think I have it working now in Rails - though maybe there are multiple answers to this and I've just discovered one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay - so adding the above lines in the different environment files and modifyg the use line to read:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Facebook::MethodFix
```

seems to work